# Decide a template declaration is a struct or a class using AST parsed with libclang

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TBox2
{
}

typedef TBox2<float> FBox2f;
```

So the template declaration in AST is a `CursorKind.CLASS_TEMPLATE`. How can I tell the template is a struct or class ?

```py
> tpl.kind
CursorKind.CLASS_TEMPLATE
> tpl.spelling
'TBox2'
> tpl.displayname
'TBox2<T>'
> tpdef.kind
CursorKind.TYPEDEF_DECL
> tpdef.type.spelling
'FBox2f'
> tpdef.underlying_typedef_typetpdef.underlying_typedef_type.spelling
'TBox2<float>'
```

Comment: `class` and `struct` are not two different things. There is only one thing (a class); declaring a `class` with `struct` changes the default visibility of member declarations. It has no other effect. So it's not retained as part of the type.

Comment: @rici Right. And this is exactly why I need to tell whether it is a `struct` or `class`. I need to generator some wrapper code for this template based on the ast. And if it is a struct I can safely access all members without concern acout the accessibility.

Comment: and some other trivial difference relies on struct when generating

Answer (score 0):

I firgure it out, you can use `Cursor.access_specifier` method to get the member is public or private.